# i want to scrape a name but get the output NONE

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image of inspected element price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7qUn.png)

i am scraping a website and want to extract the name and price but the output comes back as NONE. I have no clue what i am doing wrong here, beceause i was expecting the price and name to roll out.

website name: https://www.lordgun.com/specialized-turbo-kenevo-comp-bike-emtb-1?color=Gloss%20Dark%20Moss%20Green%20Oak%20Green

**i tried the following code:**

```
#Packages needed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

#Base website URL
baseurl = "https://www.lordgun.com/"

#New list to store all the links of the different bikes that will later be scraped
productlinks =[]

for x in range(1,2):
  ##Website waar het van af gehaald moet worden, de links voor de verdere scraping
  r = requests.get(f'https://www.lordgun.com/_road-mtb-bikes-frames?p={x}')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

  ##Searching for all the products on the webpage, these are currently defined as an "article" when inspected but could also be "div"
  productlist = soup.find_all('article', class_="article product")

  ##To test if the script finds the different products
  #print(productlist)

  for link in productlist:
    for link in link.find_all('a', href=True):
      ## possbile to test if the links are being found that needed to be found in order to later get the details
      #print(link['href'])
      productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

## To test how many links are being created
print(len(productlinks))

## to test 1 single link before the loop is generated so that there will not be a long waiting time before realising there are mistakes in this case it will be
testlink = 'https://www.lordgun.com/specialized-turbo-kenevo-comp-bike-emtb-1?color=Gloss%20Dark%20Moss%20Green%20Oak%20Green'
r = requests.get(testlink)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('h1', name_='product title')
price = soup.find('div', class_= 'prd-price')
category = soup.find('span', itemprop_='name')

print(price)
print(name)
print(category)
```

Comment: please provide your whole code

Comment: BeautifulSoup returns "None" when it can't find the selector you provided. You are getting None because you are telling BeautifulSoup to find an element that does not exist.

Comment: was struggeling to provide the whole code but now its in there!

Answer (score 0):

For the first "h1" in the site you can use this code. Many websites I mean only one page of the website have only one "h1" because of SEO

```
product_title = soup.find('h1').text.strip() 
print(product_title)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, it does work that way, but i would like to extend the code to also include other things such as price

And that results in the same error as i previous had with the title unfortunatly

Comment: I prefer to use css selectors in beautifulsoup. In this case you will not get errors, I hope

Comment: any tips on how to combine using css selectors in beautifulsoup? I am currently following a tutorial so jst figuring out how to combine the css selector with my code since im quite new

I have a css selector so thats step one, how do i input this within:

print(soup.find)

Comment: https://www.educative.io/answers/beautiful-soup-select
this link will help you, I think

Comment: install Slectorhub extension with chrome it will help you to make xpath or CSS slector to find element and scrape  data using bs4 or selenium.